# ValueError when adding new observations to SARIMAX model before making a new n-step ahead forecast

Tags: python, statsmodels, arima, forecast

I built a SARIMAX model on a timeseries. The goal is now to use this model to regularly make forecasts for the next 12 weeks.

My training data has 152 observations. I could build forecasts that then forecast the values for the next 12 observations. However, now we are 3 weeks further and I want to add the actual values of my endogenous and exogenous variables for these 3 weeks to my traindata and get the updated forecast for the next 9 weeks on these 155 observations without refitting the model.

On https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_forecasting.html I found one should be able to do this in using:

```
append_newobs = <fitted model>.append(endog=detrended_test.loc[153:155], 
                                          exog=exog_test.loc[153:155], refit=False)
fcast = append_newobs.get_forecast(9, exog=exog_test[156:])
```

However, this gives me a value error: "ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 2 dimension(s)"

How should I solve this ?

My exog_test is a Pandas dataframe with 3 observations and 12 exogenuous variables.

Relevant code blocks:

```
# =============================================================================
# ------------------------------ FIT SARIMAX ON DETRENDED DATA-----------------
# =============================================================================

exog=train[['fl_has_publicholiday', 'fl_krokusvakantie', 'fl_paasvakantie', 
             'jul', 'aug', 'fl_herfstvakantie', 'Christmas_week', 'Newyears_week', 'jan', 'mei', 
             'sep']]
modx8 = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(endog=detrended, trend='n', order=(0,0,1), seasonal_order=(0,0,1,52), exog=exog)
resx8 = modx8.fit(disp=False)

# =============================================================================
# ------------------------------ PRODUCE 12 WEEKS FORECAST -----------------
# =============================================================================

exog_test=test[['fl_has_publicholiday', 'fl_krokusvakantie', 'fl_paasvakantie', 
             'jul', 'aug', 'fl_herfstvakantie', 'Christmas_week', 'Newyears_week', 'jan', 'mei', 
             'sep']]
pred_test=resx8.get_forecast(12, exog=exog_test) #Forecast fluctuations around the trend
print('Forecast:')
print(pred_test.predicted_mean)
print('Confidence intervals:')
print(pred_test.conf_int())

# ==================================================================================================
# -----------ADD NEW OBSERVED DATA AND BUILD FORECAST ON LONGER TIMESERIES WITHOUT REFIT ------------
# ==================================================================================================

append_newobs = resx8.append(endog=detrended_test.loc[153:155], exog=exog_test.loc[153:155], 
refit=False)
fcast = append_newobs.get_forecast(9, exog=exog_test[156:]) 

This fails with the value error stated above.
```

Comment: It's solved. It was due to my detrended values on which I trained being a list and then the detrended_test was a dataframe